# Razor Pages - Show the loading Spinner using AJAX when page loading

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to load the data into a div with the loader.gif spinner when the page initially loading.

Here is the page ListViewLoading.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPagesCollection.Pages.PopUp.ListViewLoadingModel
@using Northwind_EF.Models
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <img src="/Images/Loader.gif" alt="Loading...">

    </div>
    <div id="view-all" data-url="Popup/ListViewLoading">
        <!-- Partial view will be loaded here -->
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Popup/ListViewLoading?handler=CustomerList',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    // Load the partial view
                    $('#view-all').html(result);

                    // Hide the loader
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle errors here
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ListViewLoading.cshtml.cs:

```
using EF_DBContext;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Northwind_EF.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RazorPagesCollection.Pages.PopUp
{
    public class ListViewLoadingModel : PageModel
    {
        private NorthwinDbContext Context { get; }
        public ListViewLoadingModel(NorthwinDbContext _context)
        {
            this.Context = _context;
        }

        //public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetCustomerList()
        {

            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_CustomerPartial",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Customer>(ViewData, this.Context.Customers.Take(10))
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The Partial page _CustomerPartial.cshtml:

```
@model RazorPagesCollection.Pages.PopUp.ListViewLoadingModel

<h3>From the Partial View</h3>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive" id="CustomerGrid">
    <tr>
        <th>CustomerID</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@customer.CustomerID</td>
            <td>@customer.CompanyName</td>
            <td>@customer.Address</td>
            <td>@customer.City</td>
            <td>@customer.Country</td>
            <td><a class="details" href="javascript:;">View</a></td>
            <td><a class="updatePopup" href="javascript:;">Update</a></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Updated the post based on suggestion from Rena.
The AJAX call doesn't work correctly since the page keeps calling the same page with the handler `/ListViewLoading?handler=CustomerList'` repeatedly in the browser's inspector.  Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions?  Has anyone done similar for the loading spinner for different sections on the page when a page is loading?  Do I need to use AJAX and OnGet() on different page handler to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ajax to call the partial view and upon successful retrieval, the `success` function will insert the HTML content into `view-all` div and hide the `loader` div:

```
<div id="loader"> 
    <img src="/Images/Loader.gif" alt="Loading..." >
           
</div>
<div id="view-all" data-url="Popup/ListViewLoading">
    <!-- Partial view will be loaded here -->
</div>
```

Ajax to call the partial:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Popup/ListViewLoading?handler=CustomerList',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            // Load the partial view
            $('#view-all').html(result);

            // Hide the loader
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle errors here  
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I changed the code as you suggested above in the ListViewLoading.cshtml page.  In the browser's Inspect, it keeps repeating the "/Popup/ListViewLoading?handler=CustomerList" for the ajax call.  I think it is because I am calling the same page that also has the Ajax code, so it keeps repeating.  Do I have create another separate page just to return the PartialViewResult? any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Milacay, just edit your original question and share your current code. And I will test for you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I have edited my original question.  I also use Northwind database to test.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I played around some more and got it working now, so no worries about testing.  Thanks a lot of  your help.